# Mysql - Invalid GIS data provided to function st_within

Tags: mysql-5.7, spatial-query

I have a table of with a geometry column (polygons and multipolygons) using srid 4326.

I want to check if a geometry is contained within another. I have the following sql:

```
SELECT t2.name 
FROM location_boundries t1
INNER JOIN location_boundries t2 ON  ST_Contains(t1.geom, t2.geom) 
AND t1.name = 'East Midlands'
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid GIS data provided to function st_within.
```

How do I even start to trouble shoot this? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

Been doing some testing and I'm seeing some unusual behaviour. Please below.

When I select a single record as follows it's throwing the above error however if I include multiple records then no error. So it looks like some issue with how its executing the query.

```
SELECT t2.name 
FROM location_boundries t1
INNER JOIN (select * from location_boundries where id in (2656044) ) t2 ON  
ST_Contains(t1.geom, t2.geom) 
AND  t1.name = 'East Midlands'
```

Now the same record with id `2656044` is include as follows and no error this time?

```
SELECT t2.name 
FROM location_boundries t1
INNER JOIN (select * from location_boundries where id in (2656044, 11609027, 11609030) ) t2 ON  
ST_Contains(t1.geom, t2.geom) 
AND  t1.name = 'East Midlands'
```

It's only happening when I limit to a single record in my subquery regardless of which record it is.

Comment: First print contents of the two geoms. What are you using to represt the geom? WKT, EWKT, etc. ?

Comment: @Marco I create the geometry from a geojson column in the table using the followin: `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geo_json)`

Comment: Ok, you need the make sure they are at the same projection AND they both have the same SRID. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html

Comment: @Marco please see my update above. All the records have the same SRID 4326

Comment: Are you sure 2656044 return a row? Maybe it's because of it. Try explain analyzing the query.

Comment: @Marco no rows are returned because I Know this polygon is not with the `East Midlands`. however the point I'm trying to make is that no errors are being thrown when I include multiple records inside my subquery. It is only throwing this error when I limit the subquery to a single row - regardless of which one it is i.e. the error is not specific to row id 2656044

Comment: I get it, but maybe the others rows returns something, or are you sure al of them doesn't return?